# I have laravel project working fine in localhost but after i've added new routes, url and views it says 404 Not Found in Cpanel only works localhost

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Can you please assist, I have laravel project working fine in my localhost where am using wamp.The problem arise after uploading the project to cpanel it says 404 Not found to new routes i just added and others works fine. I tried stackoverflow asked questions where the found .htaccess solutions but still didn't help.

[Error 404 Not Found Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvMdC.png)

```
**Here is my Web.php file**
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
   use App\Http\Controllers\ExcelController;
   
 //admin
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin'] ], function() {
  
    Route::get('/admin/clientsaccounts', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@accountsHome')->name('admin.clientsaccounts.index');
    Route::get('/admin/accstatements', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@statements')->name('admin.accstatements.index');
 });
```

Controller

```
public function statements(Request $request){
    
    $search = $request->input('search'); 
    $custacc =DB::table('customers')
                ->select('customers.*')
                ->where('customers.firstname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('customers.surname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
               ->orWhere('customers.idnumber', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
               ->orderby('customers.created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();

    return view('admin.statements.index')->with(compact('custacc'));
}
    public function accountsHome(Request $request){

    $search = $request->input('search'); 
    $custacc =DB::table('accounts')
                ->join('customers', 'accounts.idnumber', '=', 'customers.idnumber')
                ->select('customers.*', 'accounts.*')
                ->where('customers.firstname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('customers.surname', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('accounts.idnumber', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->orderby('accounts.created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate(10);
                
    return view('admin.accounts.index')->with(compact('custacc'));
}
```

Comment: Welcome!

The route you showed has a different URL compared to the screenshot's url. Are you sure you have written the URL in your route/page correctly? Can you also show us your blade file?

Comment: there's two urls giving me 404 Not Found.

Comment: Route::get('/admin/accstatements', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@statements')->name('admin.accstatements.index');     and    Route::get('/admin/clientsaccounts', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@accountsHome')->name('admin.accounts.index');

Comment: Please edit your post and add your blade file and your web.php file, I cannot help you if I do not know the environment I am working with

Comment: Can you try with hard reload by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+R

Comment: Where ? In control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel caching system also takes routes in consideration, to remove route cache in Laravel use the given below command:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: I ran this command and everything works fine locally then i copied routes/web.php to cpanel then i still get 404 Not Found. All these routes run under Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:admin'] ], function() {}

Answer (score -1):

you need to clear route cache in your laravel application.
put following code to your route and all request will works fine.
now, when you create new route; you just have to run this route.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
```

Comment: If route caching is the problem here, how would defining a new route to clear this cache solve it? You wouldn't be able to hit this new route as it would be a 404, due to caching... The correct answer is to run `php artisan cache:clear` via the command line, not a route.

Comment: Well i've tried running php artisan cache:clear and php artisan route:clear and it works fine in localhost but it gives me errors when i upload the code to cpanel

Comment: usually this is works. If it does not work, yo can go to laravelFolder/bootstrap/cache dicrectory then rename config.php to anything you want and reload your site.

Comment: my bootstrap/cache doesn't have config.php.

Comment: So are you really sure you did the server setup correctly? Maybe you did not delete the public folder from url

Comment: Would you please explain further on that? i have other urls like admin/leads , admin/customers and the all work fine even after uploaded to cpanel. Theres two urls giving me 404 Not Found   which is admin/accstatement and admin/accounts. They only work fine in localhost

Comment: if other routes work fine, so setup is correct. This has happened to me before. When I had a dicrectory with the same name as in the project public path. I suggest changing the route parameter to make it work temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear you rout cache every time you add new routes same with your view. With latest Laravel you can use `artisan optimize` in your command line or use the Route configuration.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Route::get('/optimize', function() {
    Artisan::call('optimize');
    return "Website is optimized";
});
```

Comment: I ran the following commands and nothing seems to be working : php artisan config:cache   |  php artisan config:clear  |  php artisan route:cache  |  php artisan route:clear | php artisan optimize --force

Comment: it only works fine in localhost but cpanel nothing works, even when i visit /optimize route it says 404 Not Found